# jdbc mysql giving me NumberFormatException

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, numberformatexception

I am trying to connect to a remote mysql database but I get the following error

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot connect to MySQL server on biomancy.com:3306. Is
here a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are trying to connect to? (
ava.lang.NumberFormatException)
        at org.gjt.mm.mysql.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
        at org.gjt.mm.mysql.jdbc2.Connection.connectionInit(Unknown Source)
        at org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
        at cliche.database.ClicheDBManager.<init>(ClicheDBManager.java:33)
        at cliche.server.ClicheExtension.init(ClicheExtension.java:43)
```

The code in the init function trigger this chain is simply:

```
myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, pass);
```

I can connect to the database using the commandline mysql from this same computer just fine using the same credentials, and it let me know I had the password wrong when I tried with the wrong password.

Thank you in advance for your help, I hope I gave enough information here.

Comment: Have you tried using an IP address instead of the host name? Also, please show the connection string, maybe there is a typo in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is the driver is not the right version.  Double check that you have a current version of the driver or try a different driver.  Also double check that mysql running on the default port (3306).

Comment: any specific mysql java drivers that you'd recommend?

Comment: Maybe Connector/J?   What are you using now and what version?

Comment: ah apparantly Connector/J is a name changed/updated version of the Driver I was using.